# cumsum with date and categorical variable in R

Tags: r, dplyr, cumsum

I have this dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(Date = c("12-01-2019","12-01-2019","12-02-2019","12-02-2019","12-02-2019","12-03-2019"),
                 Country = c("France","USA","France","USA","Colombia","USA")).
```

I would like to apply cumsum with dplyr and get this outcome:

```
Date          Country cumsum
"12-01-2019" "France"   1
"12-01-2019" "USA"      1
"12-01-2019" "Colombia" 0
"12-02-2019" "France"   2
"12-02-2019" "USA"      2
"12-02-2019" "Colombia" 1
"12-03-2019" "France"   2
"12-03-2019" "USA"      3
"12-03-2019" "Colombia" 1
```

Any suggestion?

Thank you very much for your help.

Greetings!

Comment: Where do the values you want to sum come from?`

Comment: Why does Colombia start at 0 while the others start at 1?

Comment: Because December 1st there's no case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `count` number of rows for each `Date` and `Country` combination, `complete` missing dates for each `Country` and add count as 0. Finally, for each `Country`, we can take `cumsum`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = lubridate::mdy(Date)) %>%
  count(Date, Country) %>%
  tidyr::complete(Country, Date = seq(min(Date), max(Date), by = 'day'), 
                  fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  mutate(n  = cumsum(n))


#  Country  Date           n
#  <chr>    <date>     <dbl>
#1 Colombia 2019-12-01     0
#2 Colombia 2019-12-02     1
#3 Colombia 2019-12-03     1
#4 France   2019-12-01     1
#5 France   2019-12-02     2
#6 France   2019-12-03     2
#7 USA      2019-12-01     1
#8 USA      2019-12-02     2
#9 USA      2019-12-03     3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your support! Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table` approaches  and it should be fast

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)
setDT(df)[, Date := as.IDate(Date, "%m-%d-%Y")][,
  .N, .(Date, Country)][CJ(Date, Country, unique = TRUE),
  on = .(Date, Country)][,  N := cumsum(replace_na(N, 0)),Country][]
#         Date  Country N
#1: 2019-12-01 Colombia 0
#2: 2019-12-01   France 1
#3: 2019-12-01      USA 1
#4: 2019-12-02 Colombia 1
#5: 2019-12-02   France 2
#6: 2019-12-02      USA 2
#7: 2019-12-03 Colombia 1
#8: 2019-12-03   France 2
#9: 2019-12-03      USA 3
```